# Can WaitGroup used with normal functions

Tags: go, concurrency

Can I use waitgroup with normal function and not with always goroutines
I have following type

```
type Manager struct {
   ....
   wg sync.WaitGroup
}

func (m *Manager) create() {
    m.wg.Add(1)
    defer m.wg.Done()
    ....
    ....
}
func (m *Manager) close() {
   m.wg.Wait()
}
```

It is working for me fine, I just want to know if this is correct

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you use a waitgroup in a context with no concurrent code there isn't really any point. It would be like using a mutex without needing synchronization.

Comment: I do not know if that makes sense. If `create()` and `close()` are called sequentially (in the same goroutine), does it make sense for `close()` to wait for `create()`? It does this in a sequential manner anyway.

Comment: It's not *wrong*, but it's not *right* either. It's like worrying about whether your penguins might be purple, when you have no penguins.

Comment: The code you posted is not a correct use of wait groups.   You call Done at the end of the create function,  so wait is guaranteed to have nothing to wait for.   If manager spawned one or multiple go routines in create (letting each go routine calling Done when it was finished) then this pattern would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the concurrent context, a waitgroup allows you to halt a goroutine until the group is "done". If you use the waitgroup incorrectly, you can have these erroneous outcomes:

- Less `Done` than `Add`: The waitgroup never finishes, and the waiting goroutine halts forever (either panics if all goroutines are deadlocked, or a silent failure otherwise)
- Less `Add` than `Done`: panics. See [`WaitGroup.Add`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add)

In the non-concurrent context, you won't receive any benefit from the synchronization of the waitgroup, so the only effect it can really have is demonstrating that the total amount added to the counter and the total amount taken away are equal (as is in correct use of a waitgroup). However, in the case of incorrect usage, it can result in a **silent failure** (see above), so you **should not** use it in this way.

There could be a legitimate use case where you want to increment / decrement a counter and then verify that it has been resolved to 0 at the end. In a non-concurrent context, you don't need such a fancy tool to do this: just use an `int`!

For example:

```golang
var counter int
// setup
// vv equivalent to wg.Add
counter += expectedNumberOfActions

for x := range actions {
    // do something
    // vv equivalent to wg.Done
    counter--
}

// vv achieves the purpose of wg.Wait
if counter != 0 {
   panic("oh no! the counter was not resolved correctly. there may be some bug in the implementation")
}
```